# Limit on memory allocation in windows + am I calculating this properly?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, limit

I'm writing a program that requires a lot of memory (large graph analysis).

Currently there are two main data structures in my program (taking up most of the memory). These are:

- a n*n matrix of type `int **`
- and array of length n, type `Node *`

Node, in this case, is a struct containing two ints (`sizeof(Node)` = 8)

The biggest value for n that I can run my code on is 22900, doing a bit of calculation I get:

`22900*22900 * sizeof(int) * 8 + 22900 * sizeof(Node) = 16782591360 bits`

This is 1.95375077 Gigabytes.

So question 1: am I calculating the memory usage for these two data structures properly?
and 2: Is there a 2GB memory allocation limit on windows. If so, how can I get around it?

For further information, I am on a 64bit Windows 7 machine compiling with GCC, 4GB RAM with ~3GB of free RAM at time of running.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you compile for 64 bits? If not, can you tell the compiler that your EXE supports up to 4GB?

Comment: do you really need such a huge dense matrix? What are you doing with it?

Comment: Yes I do, the time complexity / space efficiency trade off for what I'm doing is much better with an adjacency matrix rather than an adjacency list. Performance is crucial, I have arbitrary amounts of RAM that I can throw at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calculating it correctly. First, there is no reason to multiply anything by 8. The quantum of allocation in C is byte, not bit. Second, you neglect the pointer array which implements the first dimension of your matrix. So:

```
22900 * sizeof(int*) + 22900*22900*sizeof(int) + 22900*sizeof(Node) = 2097914800 bytes
```

As for useful advice, I'll leave that to the (already posted) other answer.

Comment: This should perhaps be a comment?

Comment: I don't think so. Quoting the OP: "So question 1: am I calculating the memory usage for these two data structures properly?" The answer to that question is "no".

Comment: Fair enough. Also, you're neglecting malloc overhead (it's unclear if he's pooling Nodes or mallocing them individually)

Comment: Up-voted since there are multiple answers that help me. @bdonlan I am callocing n Nodes in one go, if that's what you mean by pooling?

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely compiling for 32-bits; on windows, 32-bit processes are limited to 2G of addressable space ([with a 64-bit OS and the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag set, 4GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Compile for 64-bit and you should see your memory limit rise substantially. However, you will likely want more physical RAM before doing so; you're using half of it already and hitting swap will kill your performance.

Comment: `sizeof(Node)` would still be 8 in a 64-bit process, since `sizeof(int)` does not change.  `Node` contains two `int`s, not two pointers.

Answer (score 2):

32bit processes are limited to 2G of user-adressable memory (on most releases of windows with default settings). 64bit processes have much larger address spaces. See this note [Performance and Memory Consumption Under WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a way to give your 32bit app a 4G address space (not sure if/how GCC can build executable images with that flag set though).

Compile your code as a 64bit application and that limit should vanish (try [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: You can set the 4G flag later, if GCC doesn't support it directly. It's just a bit in the PE header.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the memory limitation, you have to compile the program in 64-bit mode; note that pointers are then 8 byte in size. The total memory usage of the matrix would be then doubled.