# Windows: track memory usage and limit threads

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory-management

I am writing a Windows based application that uses the OpenCV library for image processing. This is a multi-threaded application and each thread loads an image and processes it. My problem is that when the images are huge, the memory consumption becomes very high and the application crashes.

I want to be able to track the amount of memory my app is using(from within the app) and dynamically restrict the number of threads being created. Is there a way in Windows to track how much of permitted memory the app is using( and how much more I will be allowed).

I am using VC++( VS2010 on Windows 7).

I did look at some questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490718/track-memory-usage-in-c-and-evaluate-memory-consumption) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683843/limit-on-memory-allocation-in-windows-am-i-calculating-this-properly), but could not find any that allows tracking from within the app itself. Is this possible? Any guidelines would be helpful.

Comment: One way would be to centralise the memory allocation by holding a single memory pool in the main thread and cause worker threads to wait (if necessary) until memory is free.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it. I will look this up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will have any serious impact on the memory consumption, but it's worth of checking if you haven't already done it.

When creating a thread, if you don't specify the stack size, the system will use the same amount as for the main thread. This could be 1MB. You probably don't need large stack, so try passing 32k, 64k, 128k...